# NetBeans 12 PHP - IDE's default browser does not work

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, netbeans-12

I migrated to a new pc - switched from NetBeans 11 to NetBeans 12 using the old project configs.

In the new setup when I select IDE's default web browser for debugging (PHP7.3 + Xdebug 2.8) NetBeans opens Internet Explorer instead of opening a browser tab in the IDE.

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.0
Java: 15; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 15+36-1562
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 15+36-1562
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the default browser under `"Tools / Options / General / Web Browser"`.

Comment: Thanks! It does point to IE which solves half of the issue. Now I need to find the embedded toolkit browser